# AJAX post to database - multiple submit buttons?

Tags: php, ajax

I just started to work with javascript and ajax. So this is probably a beginner question, but I wasn't able to find a proper solution..

I want to send an id to a php script via ajax. this works fine so far: (I found it on the internet)

js:

```
$(function() {
    $(".add_button.click(function() {
        var element = $(this);
        var test = $("#submitid").val();    
        var dataString = 'content='+ test;  
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_addlink.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

php

```
<form  method="post" name="form" action="">
    <input type="submit" value="'.$value.'" id="submitid" name="submit" class="add_button"/>
</form>
```

The problem is, that i want to have multiple buttons on my page, depending on my db entries (let's say i have 5 entries in my 'test' database, there will be 5 buttons, too.) The code above doesnt work for this isuue, as all buttons have the same id.

That's how I solved this problem: I passed different ids and classes:

```
$i=1;
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    echo '  <form  method="post" name="form" action="">
                <input type="submit" value="'.$value.'" id="submitid'.$i.'" class="add_button'.$i.'"/>
            </form>';   
    $i++;
}
```

and

```
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $max_i; $i++) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".add_button<?php echo $i?>").click(function() {
        var element = $(this);
        var test = $("#submitid<?php echo $i?>").val(); 
        var dataString = 'content='+ test;  
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_addlink.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false 
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

This actually works, but I think it's not a very clean solution, because then i have like 50 < script > < / script  > codes at the end..

Any ideas how to do it in a better way?

Comment: Use classes, not id's.

Comment: oh.. ofc. how stupid to work with ids. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first way is almost there. `$(".add_button")` gets all the elements with class `add_button`, and that code will bind all the buttons with the event handler. No need to use IDs.
Javascript:

```
    $(".add_button").click(function() {
        var dataString = 'content='+ $(this).val(); 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_addlink.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false
        });
        return false;
    });
```

php

```
<form  method="post" name="form" action="">
    <input type="submit" value="'.$value.'" class="add_button"/>
</form>
```